# Как в дебаггере SASM увидеть содержание регистров FPU?

Tags: ассемблер, sasm

Изучаю FPU, но в дебаггере не могу понять как увидеть содержимое его регистров. Обычные регистры записываются так: `$eax`, но аналогично (а-ля `$st0`) выдаёт ошибку.

Благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меню "Настройки" - "Общие" - "Показывать все регистры при отладке" - "Да".

Во время отладки заходим в меню "Отладка" - ставим галку "Показывать регистры".

[image: Скриншот]